# How to get data in array from database?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to get data into array from database but i am stuck here need to solve this issue

```
public class FeaturedItemList
{
  public List<PagingProduct> products { get; set; }
}

public class PagingProduct
{
  public string name { get; set; }
}

public class PagingProductRepository
{
  public ObservableCollection<PagingProduct> pagingProducts { get; set; }
  public FeaturedItemList products;

  public PagingProductRepository() { }

  public async void GetData()
  {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://orangepotato.rjcpacking.com/index.php?route=api/login/getFeaturedProducts");

    products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeaturedItemList>(json);                                
 }

 internal string[] names= new string[]
 {
    // Here i want to get data   
 };
```

if i use static data like this

```
internal string names;
{
   "1500 Reviews", "1000 Reviews", "1200 Reviews", "1400 Reviews", "1600 Reviews",
   "1700 Reviews", "1800 Reviews", "1900 Reviews", "2500 Reviews", "1500 Reviews",
};
```

It works fine, but i need to get data from database

Comment: Your question is unclear because is incomplete. What is the definition of a _FeaturedItemList_ object? How it is related to the names array? Where do you expect to find the values to put into the names array?

Comment: i have edit my question and added 2 classes for u to understand

Comment: Using async void is bad pratice see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: I don't see any code related to a database.

Comment: @JeroenHeier - I have a feeling the database is from some sort of web service. Perhaps the question title could have been clearer.

Comment: If get data from sql databse:`SQLiteAsyncConnection database;
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>().Wait();
            names = database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
var featuredItemList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeaturedItemList>(json);
names = featuredItemList.products.Select( p=> p.name ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Obviously, you'd need to check that json isn't empty before processing it.